# A question relted to NSMUtabledata

Tags: iphone

NSDATA *data1;
NSDATA *data2;
NSDATA *data3;

I want to convert my this all 3 data's to bytearray and then again i want to append it to the 
NSMutabledata;

What Should I do For that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert them to a byte array.

```
NSMutableData *md = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data1];
[md appendData:data2];
[md appendData:data3];
```

will give you the data in `md`.